# Missing 'face' after exporting to Unity

Tags: export, faces, unity, .fbx

I was exporting my model to Unity and saw that a part of the eye ball is missing and you can see through it. Why is that?

In **Blender**:
[image]

In **Unity:**

[image]

Any idea what's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: maybe you need to flip the normal of your eye, Blender will show you both sides of the face the same way, but in a game engine I guess you'll only see the side with normal

Comment: That was it! plus a crazy vertex left in the black area! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flip the normals of your eye faces, Blender will show you both sides of the faces, but in a game engine you'll only see the side with normal.